# Keyboard keys not working in chrome.app when in full-screen

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

When switching to full-screen in a Google Chrome Packaged app (using `webkitRequestFullScreen`), most of the keyboard keys are not working except for the space button, enter, backspace and arrows.

Is there any way that the other keys (all numbers and letters) are functional when in full-screen mode?

I noticed that most keys do not trigger `keydown`, `keypress` and `keyup` events.

This is a problem especially when working on apps like for example a VNC client, where key events are crucial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two fullscreen implementations, which differ by a single character. Use the newer [HTML Fullscreen specification](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html) with `webkitRequestFullscreen` (lower case 'screen').

The [older specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_fullscreen_mode) accessed with `webkitRequestFullScreen` (upper case 'Screen') needs `Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT` for keyboard support. Avoid, as this is likely to be deprecated.

Comment: Keyboard keys are now working using webkitRequestFullscreen(), thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Yeah, great. Two different functions, with only a uppercase letter defining them ;) Thanks tho

Comment: just one of the many quirks dealing with browsers and the fullscreen API... this was very helpful.